# My EXE runs fine if it has the rest of the debug folder available, but not standalone

Tags: c#, wpf, exe

I have a WPF application, that I want to deploy as standalone so that a user can download it from a website and run it without having to install it.

It runs fine (from any machine) so long as it has all of the files in the debug folder with it:

[image]

If I try to run just the EXE without the other files if crashes. Is there a way I can streamline these files into the EXE so it can be run standalone?

(There is a background image on the form, but this is set to Build Action = Resource, so I don't think this is the issue. Also the image does not have to copied to the other machine in order to run, just the files shown above.)
    The errors from the event log are:

```
Faulting application name: AMBootstrapper.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x572caffc
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.162, time stamp: 0x56cd55ab
Exception code: 0xe0434352
```

and:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
```

EDIT: After more testing I can remove most of the files, but the one I can't is **AMBootStrapper.exe.config**

Comment: What error does it crash with? Check your windows event log and [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37075367/edit) with the output of the error information

Comment: Are you sure that's the minimal set of files it requires? I'd have thought the only one that potentially causes it to fail to run would be the first config (assuming you're running the first exe)

Comment: Good thinking @ScottChamberlain - adding it to the question now

Comment: `pdb` files contain debug symbols, they aren't required to run your application. `vshost` isn't launched by the application (rather, it launches the application when running inside of VS), so you shouldn't need it. The `config` file of the assembly may be required, but note that it can't be part of the assembly -- it must always be separate.

Comment: There should be a 2nd error in the event log next to that one that has the .net error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - you are correct. I can remove all the files except for AMBootstrapper.exe.config

Comment: Are there for example appSettings, connectionStrings or WCF services in the configuration file that might result in an exception where the file is not present?

Comment: @BenJackson - Think you've hit the nail on the head. There's a WCF service in the app.config. Assume I'll need to take it out of there and put it in the code, right?

Comment: @Ben - yes, it's probably best to configure the WCF artifacts in code.  There is a way of dynamically loading WCF configuration XML from e.g. an embedded resource but it involves wriring a custom ChannelFactory and best avoided if possible.

Comment: @BenJackson - thanks for this. If you could point me in the direction of any documentation on configuring it this way I'd be most grateful. Never consumed a WCF service without a config file before.

Comment: @Ben - sorry, I was offline for quite a while yesterday, glad you have it sorted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @BenJackson the issue was that the WCF service details were in the app config.

Solution was to remove this from app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="184320" maxBufferPoolSize="184320" >
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://svc.myserver.com/MyService/Service.svc/Service.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
            contract="MyService.IService" name="WSHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And replace with this in code:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.AllowCookies = true;
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 184320;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 183420;
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://svc.myserver.com/MyService/Service.svc/Service.svc");

MyService.MyClient c = new MyService.MyClient(binding, address);
```